# Open HTML file on Android with Python androidhelper / SL4A

Tags: android, python-2.7, sl4a, qpython

using qpython (python2.x), from what i can see, the way to open a web browser on android from a python script is by first getting the "application uri?" by calling

```
  from androidhelper import Android
  droid = Android()
  droid.getLaunchableApplications()
```

where i got "com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main" as my "application uri?"
next, i use droid.startActivity() to launch the application. the syntax is as follows.

```
  startActivity(
      String action,
      String uri[optional],
      String type[optional]: MIME type/subtype of the URI,
      JSONObject extras[optional]: a Map of extras to add to the Intent,
      Boolean wait[optional]: block until the user exits the started activity,
      String packagename[optional]: name of package. If used, requires classname to be useful,
      String classname[optional]: name of class. If used, requires packagename to be useful)
```

a working use of this code that i googled is below. it opens up the youtube application and goes to a specific video.

```
  droid.startActivity('android.intent.action.VIEW', 
      'vnd.youtube:3nH_T9fLd_Q', None, None, False, None, None)
```

but i cant quite figure out how to turn this code into the code i need. i want to open the file "new.html" (located in the current working directory) and display it in the chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

[sl4a documentation](http://www.mithril.com.au/android/doc/AndroidFacade.html)

I tried lots of different ways to do what you want to do:

**The best way: intent with category**

Make an intent with [CATEGORY_BROWSABLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_BROWSABLE). This should launch an app to browse the HTML; if there are multiple apps, it'll ask the user which to launch.

```
from androidhelper import Android
droid = Android()
uri2open = "file:///sdcard/qpython/scripts/test.html"
intent2start = droid.makeIntent("android.intent.action.VIEW", uri2open, "text/html", None, [u"android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"], None, None, None)
print(droid.startActivityForResultIntent(intent2start.result))
```

**System browser**

Launch the built-in Android system browser.

```
droid.startActivity("android.intent.action.VIEW", uri2open, "text/html", None, False, "com.android.browser", "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity")
```

**HTML viewer**

Just view, giving no package name and class name. Usually Android will launch the HTML viewer.

```
droid.startActivity("android.intent.action.VIEW", uri2open, "text/html", None, False, None, None)
```

**Sl4a webViewShow**

Use sl4a's `webViewShow` directly.

```
droid.webViewShow(uri2open)
```

*If you like this answer, remember to **upvote** or set mine as the answer! Hope this help you!*